# Characterization of a virtually nilpotent group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a group that has an increasing sequence of subgroups $G_i \le G_{i+1}$ satisfying the following properties.

(a) $G=\bigcup_{i\ge 1} G_i$.

(b) Each $G_i$ contains a nilpotent subgroup $N_i$ such that $[G_i:N_i] \le k$ for some constant $k$ independent of $i$.

Can we find a nilpotent subgroup $N \le G$ such that $[G:N]<\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, despite getting four upvotes, my previous answer was wrong, so I have deleted it. The result is false even when $k=1$.

As counterexample, for each $i \ge 1$, let $H_i$ be a finite nilpotent group of class $i$. For example, we could choose $H_i$ to be the dihedral group of order $2^{i+2}$.

Now let $G_i = H_1 \times H_2 \times \cdots \times H_i$ for all $i$, with the natural embedding of $G_i$ into $G_{i+1}$. Then $G := \cup_{i \ge 1} G_i = \times_{i \ge 1} H_i$ is not nilpotent, because it has subgroups that are nilpotent of class $i$ for each $i$.

But we need to prove that $G$ does not have a nilpotent subgroup of finite index. A subgroup of finite index would have to project onto $H_i$ for all but finitely many $i$, and so again it could not be nilpotent.

Comment: Could you add the proof of the statement under the extra assumption that all nilpotent groups $N_i$ have uniformly bounded nilpotency class? It is not clear to me how this follows from your earlier answer.

Comment: I have deleted that claim for now. I am still thinking about it.

Comment: Right: In order to get prove that G is VN, you have to add the assumption that subgroups  $N_i$ have uniformly bounded class.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you prove that it is true under that assumption? I have been struggling to get the details right.

Comment: I do not have time for this right now, but check Theorem 13.94 in the book by Drutu and Kapovich "Geometric Group Theory" where the result is proven for virtually solvable groups.